# Is there some programs about the fast inverse descrete time Fourier transform

Tags: numerical-integration, fourier-analysis, number-theory, signal-processing

At first, I give the definition of the inverse discrete-time Fourier transform

$$\phi(s)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\exp(iks)f(k)dk$$

Here what  I use is

```
ResourceFunction["NInverseFourierSequenceTransform"][GGG[k, t], k, 1]
```

It seems that for some complex functions, the above command is very slow.

Are there some programs which are faster than the 'NInverseFourierSequenceTransform'?

Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: The function I used is very complex which needs more time to compute.

Comment: Have you looked at FourierTransform and its inverse?

Comment: @bills   The upper and the bottom limits of the integral of the InverseFourierTransform are different from the inverse discrete-time Fourier transform.

Comment: If you're assuming periodicity, then how about FourierSinCoefficient and/or FourierCosCoefficient, or FourierSinSeries and/or FourierCosSeries?